# Boustrophedon Text Editing?

Tags: emacs, typography

I would like to edit text in boustrophedon in emacs. For those of you who don't know boustrophedon text direction goes "like an ox turns" in a field or like a printer inkjet. For the same reasons this is efficient on a farm or in a printer this text is very efficient to read once you get used to it (which doesn't take too long).

more on boustrophedon typesetting/layout:
http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/aleph/2004-March/000094.html

To my knowledge there are no implementations of this typesetting style and I am stumped on how to implement it.

Any ideas as to how this could be done?

Thanks,
Andreas

Comment: No offence, but if you actually want to write that way, you're weird. :-)

Comment: I would understand it if, instead of mirroring the alternate lines, it would<br/> line. the on words the of order the reverse

Comment: Would mirror the letters, actually. Supporting boustrophedon would be an extension of supporting mixed bi-directional text, I imagine.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: This is efficient for continuous reading -- but a right-left line can ONLY be read right to left. IE, random-access is screwed-up for alternating lines (can't read left-most). This was efficient when incising on clay tablets, but for text editors??? Interesting....

Comment: Have you tried c-x m-c m-boustrophedon? :P :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that advising self-insert-command, intercepting the events, and modifying the buffer accordingly is what you want to do.  You will then need to rebind the directional commands (forward-char and friends are reversed on opposite lines), and so on.

A lot of work, but definitely possible.

Before you write anything too complicated, ask on emacs-devel.  As the comments suggest, it might be useful to have generic support for something like this... although arbitrary snippets of text with different directions won't word-wrap (when inserting) the same way your text will.

Edit:  Apparently advising self-insert-command doesn't quite work for this, so you will need to setup a keymap (and bind ?a to (my-new-insert-command ?a) and so on...).

Answer (score 1):

You could write it in `sed` I hacked the `rev` script from the sed1liners text to skip a line and then `rev` every other line:

`alias boustrophedon='sed -n "1{p;b a};{/\n/!G;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//;p};n;p;:a"'`

`$> echo -en "This\nis\nBoustrou...\ntext\non\ndisplay\nhere.\n" | boustrophedon`

```
This
si
Boustrou...
txet
on
yalpsid
here.
```

Or, if you want to process a whole file:

`$> boustrophedon <filename>`